# DIV SLIDER BOTTOM CSS

Tags: css

Olá,

Pretendo utilizar o mesmo código que criei neste [exemplo jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n0L5psuq/), para que a DIV que está oculta, ao invés de aparecer do topo, aparaça do footer (de baixo para cima).

Vejam este exemplo, clicando no circulo amarelo.

E depois através desta imagem, terem noção do que preciso.

Confesso que tentei, mas não consegui chegar neste resultado.

```css
body {
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
}

.dialog {
 width: 300px;
}

.container {
 border: none;
 box-shadow: 0 40px 77px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22), 0 27px 24px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
 position: relative;
 background-color: #fff;
 background-clip: padding-box;
 outline: 0;
}

.container .header {
 min-height: 16px;
 border: none;
 background: #fff !important;
 color: #3f51b5;
}

.container .title {
 line-height: 0;
}

.content {
 background-color: #efefef;
 height: 350px;
 padding-top: 5px;
 padding-bottom: 5px;
 padding-left: 15px;
 padding-right: 15px;
}

.footer {
 text-align: right;
 border-top: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
 padding: 8px 0;
}

.pt-5 {
 padding-top: 5px !important;
}

.px-15 {
 padding-right: 15px !important;
 padding-left: 15px !important;
}

.mt-0 {
 margin-top: 0px !important;
}


/* DIV-IMAGE */

.header {
 position: relative!important;
 z-index: 20!important;
}

.view-image .header {
 box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
}

.show-image {
 background: rgb(232, 216, 49);
 color: rgba(124, 98, 152, 1);
 width: 40px;
 height: 40px;
 text-align: center;
 position: absolute;
 right: 1em;
 bottom: 0;
 margin-bottom: -15px;
 border-radius: 100%;
 font-size: 16px;
 cursor: pointer;
 box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
 transition: all .3s;
}

.view-image .show-image {
 -webkit-transform: rotateX(-180deg);
 transform: rotateX(-180deg);
 box-shadow: 0px -2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
}

.icon-nocode,
.icon-yepcode {
 transition: opacity .3s;
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 line-height: 40px;
}

.icon-nocode {
 opacity: 0;
}

.view-image .icon-nocode {
 opacity: 1;
}

.view-image .icon-yepcode {
 opacity: 0;
}

.panel-image {
 box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
 border-radius: 8px;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.div-image {
 z-index: 5;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 height: 300px;
 background: rgba(124, 98, 152, 0.94);
 color: rgba(245, 247, 247, 0.92);
 padding: 0em 1em;
 transition: all .4s;
 -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
 transform: translateY(-100%);
}

.view-image .div-image {
 -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
 transform: translateY(0);
 box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.36);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html class="">  
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <title>To push</title>
    </head>
    <body>
 <div id="panel-image" class="dialog panel-image">
  <div class="container " STYLE="border-radius: 8px!important;">
   <div class="header" STYLE="padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 15px; padding-top: 20px; padding-bottom: 20px; border-top-left-radius: 8px!important; border-top-right-radius: 8px!important;">
    <h4 class="title">
     <span>TITLE</span>
    </h4>
    <span id="show-image" class="show-image">
                    <i class="ion-eye icon-yepcode"></i>
                    <i class="ion-eye-disabled icon-nocode"></i>
                </span>
   </div>
   <div id="content" class="content" style="">     
    <div class="div-image"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="footer mt-0 pt-5 pb-15 px-15">
       <button id="user-close" class="matter-button-text matter-primary mr-5" data-dismiss="modal">CLOSE</button>
    <button id="user-save" class="matter-button-unelevated matter-primary" data-pos="bottom-left">SAVE</button>
   </div>
  </div><!-- modal-content -->
 </div><!-- modal --> 
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
 <script>
     var panelImage = document.getElementById('panel-image'),
        showImage = document.getElementById('show-image');

        showImage.addEventListener('click', _toggleImage);

        function _toggleImage() {
            panelImage.classList.toggle('view-image');
        }
 </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vamos lá.

Na .div-image você precisa jogá-la pra baixo.
Retire o *top: 0* e coloque o *bottom: 0*.
Agora temos que jogá-la pra fora da tela. Podemos usar o mesmo translate usado. Use translateY(100%). O translate é relativo ao tamanho do elemento.

```
.div-image {
    z-index: 5;
    position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 300px;
    background: rgba(124, 98, 152, 0.94);
    color: rgba(245, 247, 247, 0.92);
    padding: 0em 1em;
    transition: all .4s;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(100%);
    transform: translateY(100%);
}

.view-image .div-image {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.36);
}
```